# Adding users (and rows) to multiple worksheets using a userform

Tags: excel, vba, rows

I had hoped to be able to resolve this problem myself, after being provided with a solution to my earlier problem of deleting rows but I have realised that it is not as straightforward as I thought.

I have a number of worksheets in a workbook which are used to collect various data on students.

Each worksheet begins with the pupil names and details about them - these are copied from a 'master data' worksheet - and the various data is entered into the subsequent columns on each worksheet.

I have a userform to add and delete students from all of the worksheets.

I have code which I have modified from Roy Cox which adds a student at the bottom of the master data list and then sorts the data so that the student is included in the correct class in the correct alphabetical ordered place.

EDITED 11/09 - 16:34 - Whole code copied for clarity.

```
Private Sub cmbAdd_Click()
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim l As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' 1) ADD NEW ROW TO EACH WORKSHEET, COPYING FORMAT AND FORMULAE

For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Rows(Selection.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    With Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
        .EntireRow.Copy
            With .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
            On Error Resume Next
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    On Error GoTo 0
            End With
    End With
Next Sh

' 2) COPY NEW CHILD FROM USERFORM TO MASTER DATA WORKSHEET

Dim LR As Long
    LR = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set c = Range("A" & LR + 1)

    With Me
    c.Value = .TextBox14.Value
    c.Offset(0, 1).Value = .TextBox1.Value
    c.Offset(0, 2).Value = .TextBox2.Value
    c.Offset(0, 3).Value = .TextBox3.Value
    c.Offset(0, 4).Value = .TextBox4.Value
    c.Offset(0, 5).Value = .TextBox24.Value
    c.Offset(0, 7).Value = .TextBox25.Value
    c.Offset(0, 8).Value = .TextBox26.Value
    c.Offset(0, 9).Value = .TextBox5.Value
    c.Offset(0, 11).Value = .TextBox27.Value
    c.Offset(0, 12).Value = .TextBox28.Value
    c.Offset(0, 13).Value = .TextBox29.Value
    c.Offset(0, 14).Value = .TextBox30.Value
    c.Offset(0, 15).Value = .TextBox31.Value
    c.Offset(0, 16).Value = .TextBox32.Value
    c.Offset(0, 17).Value = .TextBox33.Value
    Call ClearControls
End With

' 3) FILL EMPTY CHARACTERISTICS CELLS ON MASTER DATA WORKSHEET

Dim rCell   As Range
Dim rRng    As Range

For Each rRng In ActiveSheet.[A3].Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 2)
    If IsEmpty(rRng) Then GoTo NextRow
    For Each rCell In rRng.Offset(0, 7).Resize(1, 14)
        If IsEmpty(rCell) Then rCell.Value = "N"
    Next rCell
NextRow:
Next rRng

' 4) SORT DATA TO INCLUDE NEW CHILD ON EACH WORKSHEET

 Call ResortData

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The ResortData sub is also added, below:

```
Sub ResortData()

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

Range("A4:BE" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("C4:C" & LastRow), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
Key2:=Range("B4:B" & LastRow), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo ' CHANGE 'BE' TO LAST COLUMN OF SPREADSHEET

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Currently the 'master data' sheet is updated with the new pupil and 3 additional rows (there are 3 other worksheets in my trial workbook so I assume that is why).

How do I ensure that the code adds one new row to each worksheet before completing steps 2 and 3 on the master sheet and then step 4 on each worksheet?

(I need step 4 to be completed on each worksheet separately as the data collected and column headings are different on each worksheet from column V onwards)

Thanks for any advice you can provide.

Comment: Bit confused, so you say that 3 lines were added but then say `how do I ensure that the code adds a new line`? Maybe I'm missing something. Just as pointers: in your `For` loop, to ensure that a line is added to all sheets, make sure that you either use **`Sh`** when you reference cells/range in the worksheet or use: **`With Sh`**. For point 4: I would add something like `Inc_` in the name of all sheets that you want to add lines to. Then in your `For` loop, you can check if the sheet name has `Inc_` in it. If it does, add your lines, otherwise ignore it

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I need one new row to be added per worksheet so that the new student's details can be copied into it and space made for the student's data to be entered on the various worksheets. I am currently getting 4 rows (as I have 4 worksheets?) to the master data sheet. These are helpful pointers for the next step in my problem solving! Thanks Zac.

Comment: I suspect that rows are getting added to your master sheet because you are not explicitly stating which sheet you are working with. If you add the `Sh` as I mentioned in my last comment, I suspect that should cure the line adding issue

Comment: Hi Zac, I added `With Sh` at the start of the `For` loop and `End With` at the end but it has not made a difference to the outcome - I still have 4 lines added to the master data worksheet. Have I understood what you meant correctly?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I ensure that the code adds a new line to each worksheet before completing steps 2 and 3 on the master sheet and then step 4 on each worksheet?

Well, simply put each step into separate loop.

```
For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    'code for e.g. step 1'

Next Sh
```

And put it into right order.

> Also, thinking ahead, I plan to add some additional worksheets to the workbook which will be formatted differently and which will analyse the data and present various aspects of the data in tables and templates to be printed. Is it possible to write the code so that these sheets are not affected?

You can exlude some worksheets with If statement

```
For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sh.Name <> "Sheet2" And Sh.Name <> "Sheet3" Then
        'code'
    End If
Next Sh
```

Or the other way round:

```
For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sh.Name = "Sheet2" Or Sh.Name = "Sheet3" Then
        'code'
    End If
Next Sh
```

Answer (score 0):

So looking at your `For` loop, what you are doing is: you pickup each sheet in your workbook and then you reference cells on the active sheet rather than the sheet you want to reference. This is because when you reference cells/range, you don't explicitly say which sheet to add the line to.. Try the code below (I haven't tested the code):

```
Dim Sh As Worksheet

For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ' Use the current worksheet
    With Sh

        ' Notice the dots(.) infront of Cells and Rows. This is now referencing the cells and rows in 'Sh' sheet
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
        .Rows(Selection.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown

        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
            .EntireRow.Copy
            With .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
                On Error Resume Next
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
                On Error GoTo 0
            End With
        End With
    End With
Next Sh
```